# jquery alternative function for window.getSelection() function

Tags: jquery

i need window.getSelection() alternative function in jquery. please any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

getSelection() will not work prior to IE9.

See my answer here for a way to handle this for a particular question that might get you started as you have no other details that we can go by to assist you more specifically.

[getSelection() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie/5425913#5425913)

EDIT: I took the time to refine this just a bit.  See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/wqDWV/