# getSelection() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Can someone help me get this code working in IE please:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Alex Thomas</p>
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.color = "red";
    span.appendChild(selectionContents);
    range.insertNode(span);
});
```

Coded up here: http://jsfiddle.net/WdrC2/

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Alex IE prior to 9 does not implement `getSelection()`.

Comment: The code works for me in Chrome 8. I selected the text and clicked the button, and the text became red, so something works.

Comment: @Alex Your demo works in all current browsers( IE9, FF4, Chrome 10, Safari 5, and Opera 11).

Comment: +1 This is a great getSelection demo.

Comment: Unfortunately i need it to work in IE6+ humph!

Comment: +1 excellent question and demo

Comment: @Alex I believe IE implements the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties. You might want to look into that...

Comment: cheers @Šime Vidas ill give it a try...

Comment: You can replace these lines:    selectionContents = range.extractContents();
span.appendChild(selectionContents);
range.insertNode(span);

With this:
range.surroundContents(span);

Answer (score 24, accepted):

IE prior to 9 doesn't support `window.getSelection()`. You can use `document.selection` instead (see [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for the description). This selection object has a method `createRange()` that returns a `TextRange` object (see [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for details).

Note that both the `selection` and `textrange` objects are Microsofts own implementation and do not follow the W3C standards. You can read more about the `textrange` and `range` issues on [www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html).

The following implementation works in IE:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML("<span style='color: red'>" + range.htmlText + "</span>");
});
```

It's not nearly as nice as the other implementation since you have to work with strings instead of the dom. There is a little hack where you paste `<span id="myUniqueId"></span>` as a placeholder, and afterwards replace it using the dom. You still have to work with `range.htmlText` or `range.text` though.

BTW: the above implementation is obviously IE only. You have to use some browser capability detection to decide which version to use.

Comment: Are you sure IE9 doesn't support `window.getSelection()`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975169(v=vs.85).aspx says it does..

Comment: @Rijk You are right, that's why I wrote "IE *prior* to 9 doesn't support window.getSelection()." :)

Comment: In IE 11 `document.selection` returns `undefined` -- I am not too sure if the above answer works.

Answer (score 1):

Test this one here: http://jsfiddle.net/6BrWe/

It is a bit of a hack and not so pretty but should work in IE and other browsers - I have not done a lot of cross browser testing though :)

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    var whatBrowser = getIt();
    if (whatIsIt == 'notIE' && whatBrowser) {
        notIE(whatBrowser);
    }
    else if (whatIsIt == "isIE"&& whatBrowser) {
        isIE(whatBrowser);
    };
});

var whatIsIt = "";

function getIt() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        whatIsIt = "notIE";
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) {
        whatIsIt = "notIE";
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            whatIsIt = "isIE";
            return selection;
        };
        return false;
    };
    return false;
};

function isIE(selection) {
    if (selection) {
        var selectionContents = selection.text;
        if (selectionContents) {
            selection.pasteHTML('<span class="reddy">' + selectionContents + '</span>');
        };
    };
};

function notIE(selection) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className= "reddy";
    span.appendChild(selectionContents);
    range.insertNode(span);
};
```

Comment: With all of that JS, I have to wonder why you didn't just do a `document.getElementById("click").onclick` for the first line. However, +1 for a thorough answer that uses feature detection.

Comment: OP had jQuery there, so I did not change that part

Answer (score -4):

If you want to color "Alex Thomas" to red you can do

**HTML**

```
<p id='txt'>Alex Thomas</p>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='click' />
```

**JS**

```
$('#click').click(function(){
  $('#txt').attr('color','Red');
});
```

Comment: He wants to make the highlighted section of 'Alex Thomas' red, not the whole thing.