# getSelection() not working for <iframe> in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

Leading on from my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie), which was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie#answer-5424222) by [Elian Ebbing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532870/elian-ebbing). I now need to get this working for an iframe (dont ask).

It's basically a wisiwig editor that uses an iframe.

I've coded up the test environment on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMRMv/).

Code is as follows:

**CSS:**

```
h1{font-size:150%; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; margin:20px auto 10px;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Normal Text (works)</h1>
<p>Alex Thomas</p>
<button id="click">Click</button>

<h1>iFrame</h1>
<p>Type in some text:</p>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<br /><button id="iClick">Click</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(makeEdit,10);
});

$('#click').click(function(){
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML("<span style='color: red'>" + range.htmlText + "</span>");
});

$('#iClick').click(function(){
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML("<span style='color: red'>" + range.htmlText + "</span>");
});

function makeEdit(){
  document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow. document.designMode="on";
};
```

I really hope someone can help me out... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the iframe's `document` object to create the TextRanges you use:

```
function makeIframeSelectionRed() {
    var range = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML("<span style='color: red'>" + range.htmlText + "</span>");
}

$('#click').click(makeIframeSelectionRed);

$('#iClick').click(makeIframeSelectionRed);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim, any chance you could add it to my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HMRMv/). I cant seem to get it to work. Thanks