# Retrieve selected text in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection, getselection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getSelection() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie)

I was trying to get the selected content, and I found this:

```
   window.getSelection().toString();
```

It works in most of the browser, except the obvious, IE.

So, what to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Only IE9 onwards supports `window.getSelection()`. You can use `document.selection` instead in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

The full syntax was:

```
document.selection.createRange().text;
```