# removeAllRanges() in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, selection

I am writing a drag and drop script. The problem when holding down the mouse and moving it along the page is that it starts selecting the text. I found a way to prevent this by calling...

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
```

...when moving the mouse. As usual, I am having trouble with Internet Explorer. Is there an equivalent to make this method work in <IE9 (No plug-ins, pure JavaScript)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [getSelection() not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire selection model is totally different in older IEs. There's no `window.getSelection()` nor `Range` objects like in modern browsers. You've to get familiar with [TextRange Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) etc. when implementing selections and ranges in IE<9.

However, your problem with IE can be solved in a simple way. Attach `onselectstart` event to `window` (or any element you need). In a handler prevent the default action and cancel bubbling. Something like this:

```
window.attachEvent('onselectstart', function (e) {
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent code in old IE (up to and including version 8) is

```
document.selection.empty();
```

Relevant MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx