# Selected text in an asp.net text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an old asp.net app originally at .net 2.0 which framework is upgraded to 4.0 (this is not related to my problem, just informing in details) and I'm using Internet Explorer 11. Here I'm facing a problem, I have a text box as shown bellow:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCost" runat="server" onKeyPress="return GetSelected();" MaxLength="12" TabIndex="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

In where I'm trying to check on `onKeyPress` if the user has selected/highlighted any content and trying to get the selected content. To do this I tried bellow code

**JS:**

```
function GetSelected() {
        var pass = true;
        var content = document.getElementById('<%= txtCost.ClientID %>').value;

        if (content.length == 2 && key !== 46) {

            if (document.getSelection != undefined) { //true, if there is any selected content

                //do something with selected content
                pass = false;
            }
            else //if no content selected then return false
            {
                pass = false;
            }
        }
    return pass;
}
```

but here `if (document.getSelection != undefined)` is always true even though there is no text selected in the text box. I need an `if condition` be true only if there is any selected text in that text box. Well, as I know `document.getSelection` returns a `selectionRange` object but I'm not very clear how `document.getSelection` works. Please help me to fix this.

Bellow are few referrals I followed

[link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript),
[link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421892/getselection-not-working-in-ie)